# Set Cell Subview Position After Height Set?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, height

In my app I have a tableview, with a custom tableviewcell and that has a UIImageView in it.

However, my issue. `- (void)configureCell:(MyCustomCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`where I set the frame of my image is called before `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` where I set the cell height.

Meaning, the image position isn't correct (its dynamic, changes depending on cell height).

How do you suggest I get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When do you call your `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method? In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation?

Anyway, try to set you image height in `tableView:willDisplayCell:` delegate method instead. This method is called just bore the cell is displayed on screen so that it will not be resized afterwards by other internal methods.

*Besides, can't you use the AutoresizingMask property to make your image view resize automatically depending on its container view (the cell)?*